# How to extract the dates from the Upcoming Events section using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried to get these dates from the Upcoming Events on the page https://www.python.org/

I did this with my code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_driver_path = "C:\develoment\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.python.org/")

silent = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'time')
silent2 = [x.text for x in silent]
print(silent2)
```

But when i tried to printed  I got this.

```
['2023-03-08', '2023-02-15', '2023-02-10', '2023-02-08', '2023-02-08', '2023-03-13', '2023-03-15', '2023-03-22', '2023-04-01', '2023-04-07']
```

What i´m doing wrong?

HTML snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with an example of what you're expected output should be. The image doesn't really help. Check out [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The date you have in your screenshot is present in your list. The last 5 date are from that section. What is the problem?

Comment: in this page https://www.python.org/ on the section of upcoming events you´ll see the dates and the title , the title is a <time> tag and between this there is a  <span> tag  i tried to get this two values

Answer (score 0):

The locator you have used:

```
driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'time')
```

Identifies the elements from the **Latest News** section as well from the **Upcoming Events** section. Hence you find additional entries.

---

### Solution

To extract the values only from the **Upcoming Events** section you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.python.org/")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("textContent") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.medium-widget.event-widget.last time")])
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.python.org/")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='medium-widget event-widget last']//time")])
  ```

---

To extract the texts ideally you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.python.org/')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.medium-widget.event-widget.last time")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.python.org/')
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("textContent") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='medium-widget event-widget last']//time")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['2023-03-13', '2023-03-15', '2023-03-22', '2023-04-01', '2023-04-07']
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To print date and event name from the web page you mentioned, use below code:

```
# Find all the list items  having time and event name
events = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li')

# Loop through event and extract the date and event name
for event in events:
    date = event.find_element_by_css_selector('time').get_attribute('datetime')[:10]
    name = event.find_element_by_css_selector('a').text
    print(date, name)
```

Comment: Thank you all for answer me you´re the best

Comment: @JoaquínRuiz Did above solution worked for you?